# Integer presentation in computer - C

Tags: c, binary

Does C define binary representation of integer e.g. one's, two's complement... or is this
representation processor (computer or something else) dependent?

Exmple of code written in C:

```
short a = -5;
```

Where do I need to look to know wheter `a` is two's complement `1111 1111 1111 1011` or 
signed bit representation `1000 0000 0000 0101`?

Comment: Not processor dependent, the representation is language implementation dependent.

Comment: 99.9999% it's two's complement. You can use formatting to show the value as hexadecimal (using %X with printf or sprintf).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C supports the following three representations for signed integers:

- 2's complement (the most common, you're rather unlikely to see others in practice)
- 1's complement
- sign-and-magnitude

C also allows there to be some padding (non-value) bits in the representation, which is also something very uncommon in practice.

C does not define whether integers should be stored in memory as big endian or little endian or in some other byte order.

If you want to find out how exactly integers are represented on a specific platform, you need to analyze the underlying memory. Also, if `-INT_MAX == INT_MIN + 1`, you have a 2's complement representation, otherwise it's uncertain, which one of the three it is.

I think it's safe to assume these days that there are no padding bits and the representation is 2's complement.

Comment: I would vote this up, but `-INT_MAX` might be undefined behaviour if, for example, `INT_MAX == 32768` and `INT_MIN == -32767` according to 6.5p5.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue That (`INT_MAX = 32768`) wouldn't make much sense (`INT_MIN = -32767` is OK, though).

Comment: Perhaps a better test would be: `unsigned int x = INT_MIN; x += INT_MAX; if (x != 0) { /* Two's complement */ }`

Comment: @modifiablelvalue That should do fine, yes.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue Actually, the standard says that in signed non-negative integers all value bits have the same values as in the accompanying unsigned integer. It also guarantees that unsigned integers can represent values up to and including `2^(number of value bits) - 1`. So, `INT_MAX` must be `2^(some integer) - 1` and can't be `2^(some integer)`.

Comment: How does that disqualify INT_MAX (as 32768) from having the underlying binary representation of 10000000 00000000 as both signed and unsigned ints?

Comment: Your conclusion seems invalid.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue I'm not talking about what 32768 looks like in binary. I'm saying that 32768 can't be the value of `INT_MAX`. But 32767 can.

Comment: After a careful read of 6.2.6.2, it would seem you're correct. At times like this, I wish I were a little more humble.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue I make mistakes too. We're human, so it's inevitable. :)

Answer (score 5):

It is platform dependent, same as little/big Endian.
Also the number size of certain types are platform dependent.

Answer (score 4):

The representation of an integer is something platform(processor)-dependent. See [Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Answer (score 3):

Binary representation of integer is platform dependent, if platform follows little endian then integers then -ve no.s are stored as 2's complement.

```
a= -5;
b = 5;
printf("%d %d", a, b);
printf("\n%u %u", a, b);
```

will display,

```
-5 5
4294967291 5
```

Answer (score 2):

signed short -5 is 0xFFFB. The sign + absolute value representation doesn't make sense.
Addition and substractions doesn't care about signed/unsigned type. If you add 0xFFFB and 0x0005 you'll get 0x0000. If you try 0x8005 + 0x0005 you'll get 0x800A, which would be according to your hypothesis -10 which is nonsense. The number is binary complement, but rather it is just -x = 2^16 - x (mod 2^16) for short number.

Comment: `signed short -5 is 0xFFFB` that is not guaranteed by the C standard.

Comment: Standard indeed doesn't speak about the binary representation. This means, that answer to the main question is "No" but the number representation other than the usual would be completely silly. Please, give some examples of such (or other) silly number representation.

Comment: Base-minus-two? ;) Just kidding.

Comment: The question is not about how is the number stored but how is the number represented. eg. I don't care about endianity for int64 if I want to know if number is even or odd by checking the last bit. You don't care if it is in memory as last or first or in the middle or if there is some padding anywhere around or inside the number representation.

Comment: If you want to know whether it's even or odd, cast the number to any unsigned type and do `& 1` or do `% 2` directly without casting.

Comment: That's exactly what I said.